# Getting the current visible entities in RealityKit

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Currently, RealityKit doesn't have any method that provides the currently visible entities. In SceneKit we do have a method for that particular functionality—[nodesInsideFrustum(pointOfView)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522942-nodesinsidefrustum).

Our internal solution is to create a big fake bounding box in front of the camera. We then check intersections between the "frustum" bounding box and each entity's bounding box. That, of course, is a bit cumbersome and inaccurate. I wonder if someone can come up with a better solution who is willing to share it.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? If so can you please post the solution.

Comment: No, I'm still using the implementation discribed above with some extra manipulations (checking collisions against entities that resided in the -z of the camera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine two ARView methods:

- `ARView.project(position)` to get the 2D point in screen space
- `ARView.bounds.contains(point)` to know if it's visible on screen

But it's not enough, you also have to check if the object is behind you:

- `Entity.position(relativeTo: cameraAnchor)` (with `cameraAnchor` being an `AnchorEntity(.camera)`) to have the local position
- the sign of `localPosition.z` shows if it's in front or behind the camera

Comment: I believe a negative localPosition.z would be in front of the camera. worth noting the sign meaning IMO