Identify whether 3d object (entity) is visible to user or not in visionOS
I would like to know what is the way to find if an entity is visible or not to camera when user navigates in 3d space in visionOS.
When user navigate through 3d space, if a specified entity is visible then I want to put a log as visible and if goes out of view then log should put not visible as a message.
I'm not able to figure how can we determine this. Can someone help me?

If I read your question correctly, you're trying to determine, for a particular entity, whether it lies within the frustum. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75356468/719690 outlines an approach using RealityKit.

Hi @HalMueller The solution provided https://stackoverflow.com/a/75356468/719690 makes use of ARView which is available for iOS and not VisionOS. I'm looking for solution for VisionOS.

In Compositor Services framework, there was a tangents instance property that contained tangent values (SIMD4<Float>) for the angles you could use to determine the camera's invisible planes of the viewing frustum. Now it's deprecated. No replacement has been announced so far. In other words, you don't yet have a tool to calculate whether your model falls inside the frustum or not. Let's wait for new updates.
